# EU Passport holder property/residence Portugal

Tags: portugal

I am a South African citizen, my family all hold EU passports (Irish). Can we freely buy property and live in Portugal? Thanks

Comment: Do *you* have Irish citizenship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a citizen of Ireland, you have freedom of movement in Portugal. You can live there, work there and buy property there.

Comment: This https://www.expatica.com/pt/housing/buying/what-to-consider-before-buying-property-in-portugal-105551/ might be of help

Answer (score 2):

With respect to the accepted answer, if you are not a citizen of Ireland, but your family members who are are sufficiently close for you to qualify under the free movement directive, then you can have free movement in Portugal only if you accompany (at least one of) your Irish-citizen family members there. The qualifying relationships are somewhat limited.

Comment: Hi, sorry I might not have been clear. We all hold Irish passports